# Elderberry seeds toxicity

Tags: nutrition, toxicity, fruits

I was almost ready to prepare elderberry jam, using the elderberry with its seed, but then I found some [information about seed's toxicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sambucus).

Do you know if the seed of ripe elderberries are toxic when preparing a jam?

Comment: It would help a great deal if you could state the exact species used. At least the area/region where they were collected?

Comment: Note that your reference refers to raw berries; do you plan to boil your jam?

Comment: @LangLangC they are the ones used to make jam, but I will try to look at the exact specie.

Comment: @BryanKrause yes, to make jam berries must be cooked by 40 minutes at least. That's why I asked, there is no information about cooked berries

Comment: Jams aren't always cooked, which is why I asked; they need to be if you are canning, but not everyone cans/jars their jam, depending on type.

Comment: @BryanKrause  oh I am sorry, every jam I know is made by cooking..

Answer (score 1):

From your own link

> Although the ripe, cooked berries (pulp and skin) of most species of Sambucus are edible,[6][9][10] uncooked berries and other parts of plants from this genus are poisonous.[11] The leaves, twigs, branches, seeds, and roots of Sambucus plants can contain a cyanidin glycoside. Ingesting a sufficient quantity of cyanidin glycosides may produce illnesses.[6][11]

Cooking destroys the small amount of cyanogenic glycosides found in the fruit that is poisonous.

When making jam you can [sieve out all the seeds](http://mother-natures-backyard.blogspot.co.nz/2012/08/picking-cleaning-and-processing.html).

Comment: Yes, I have read that, and that's why I made the post. The information seems..strange..but thanks anyway..

Comment: Cooking destroys the toxins.